# How to use XML to store data for my quiz maker?

Tags: java, android, xml, store

Current code: https://github.com/coldblade2000/QuizMaker/tree/Development
XML I made: http://pastebin.com/FBHVsnPA

I am making a Quiz Maker app for android and haven't been able to wrap my head around using XML to store data. I made a small XML file that I am using to test it first. It has space for 1 question and four possible answers.

I am having trouble with understanding how to add values and strings to the XML, read it, etc. I've tried most XML and android tutorials but most don't talk about using variables in it or about adding your own attributes to the elements. XML is really new to me, I only know as much as basic HTML will get me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic Java API for XML that You can use to read and write XML are `DOM` `StaX`. However DOM4J  can be better since it has easier and simple API.

This is a simple method to create an XML document

```
public void createXML() throws IOException {

    Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
    Element rootElement = document.addElement("Students");
    Element studentElement = rootElement.addElement("student").addAttribute("country", "USA");
    studentElement.addElement("id").addText("1");
    studentElement.addElement("name").addText("Peter");
    XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(new FileWriter("Students.xml"));
    //Note that You can format this XML document
    /*
     * FileWriter output = new FileWriter(new File("Students.xml"));
    OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();
    XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(output,format);<- will fomat the output
     */

    //You can print this to the console and see what it looks like
    String xmlElement = document.asXML();
    System.out.println(xmlElement);
    writer.write(document);
    writer.close();

}
```

And to read student.xml

```
public void readXML() throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException, DocumentException {
    /*Integration with DOM 
    DOMReader reader = new DOMReader();
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = reader.read(builder.parse(new File("Students.xml")));
    */
    SAXReader readerSAX = new SAXReader();
    Document document2 = readerSAX.read(new File("Students.xml"));
    Element root = document2.getRootElement();
    Student student = null;
    List<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    if (root.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("students")) {
        for (@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Iterator<Student> i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Element element = (Element) i.next();
            if ("student".equalsIgnoreCase(element.getName())) {
                student = new Student();
                for (int j = 0, size = element.nodeCount(); j < size; j++) {
                    Node node = (Node) element.node(j);
                    if (node instanceof Element) {
                        if ("id".equalsIgnoreCase(node.getName())) {
                            student.setId(Integer.parseInt(node.getText()));
                        } else if ("name".equalsIgnoreCase(node.getName())) {
                            student.setName(node.getText());
                        }
                    }
                }
                studentsList.add(student);
            }
        }
    }
    for(Student stud : studentsList){
        System.out.println(stud);           
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to understand this tomorrow when my brain isn't a pile of tired mush.

Comment: @coldblade2000 http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-dom4j/index.html check that tutorial it's really great